# HashWithIndifferentAccess when saving array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so I have these 2 classes

```
class Interface < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hardware      
end
```

and

```
class Hardware < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :interfaces
end
```

I have a form for a predefined *@hardware.interfaces* which includes array of Interfaces which is handled like below

```
<%= text_field_tag "hardware[interfaces][][name]",interface.name %>
<%= text_field_tag "hardware[interfaces][][ip]",interface.ip %>
```

Now I try to do...

```
@hardware = Hardware.find(params[:id])
@hardware.update_attributes(params[:hardware])
```

and it throws the error

```
Interface(#37298420) expected, got HashWithIndifferentAccess(#24204840)
```

Could someone clue me in on what's going on? and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update_attributes updates the model attributes.. and you are trying to update another model attributes (the Interface class)

you want to use nested form & accepts_nested_attributes_for - you can see how in this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#nested-object-forms)

Comment: Don't forget to use :interface_attributes instead of interfaces[] in your forms.